# mongo db select nasted array in nasted array (partial field)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

mongo db select one, nasted array in nasted arry id

```
id : "root"
age : 70,
sons : { id : "son1",
        age : 40
        grandSon : {
          id : "grand1",
          age : 10
      } ,
       { id : "son2",
        age : 40
        grandSon : {
          id : "grand1",
          age : 10
      }
}
```

i want to select sons(son1, son2) id, age  execpt for grandSon
how can i have to do??

like this code..

```
let condition: any = { id: grandId}

let select: any = {
id: 1
, "sons.$.id": 1
, "sons.$.age": 1
, "sons.$.grandSon": 0
}
selectOne(~~~)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let try with this.

Let this be the document.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5cc7d8e88c33e065c56b0883"),
"age" : 70.0,
"sons" : [ 
    {
        "id" : "son1",
        "age" : 40.0,
        "grandSon" : {
            "id" : "grand1",
            "age" : 10.0
        }
    }, 
    {
        "id" : "son2",
        "age" : 40.0,
        "grandSon" : {
            "id" : "grand1",
            "age" : 10.0
        }
    }
 ]
}
```

And the query is

`db.collection.find({},{age:0, 'sons.grandSon': 0 });`

Result

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5cc7d8e88c33e065c56b0883"),
"sons" : [ 
    {
        "id" : "son1",
        "age" : 40.0
    }, 
    {
        "id" : "son2",
        "age" : 40.0
    }
]
}
```